# What are the different methods to expedite the data retrieval from database?

Tags: data-retrieval

How can we expedite the data retrieval from the database for my web site which is extensively updating and fetching data from database.

Comment: What language, platform and web framework are you on?

Answer (score 1):

Updating slows down databases. If you want to have high-performance reads while performing updates, you might try the following:

- Cluster your database. Have multiple databases to handle read queries, just do the writes to a single database, and distribute the updates in an orderly fashion. (Wikipedia does this, I'm told.)
- Increase the RAM in your database (ie: attack database performance).
- Decrease the number of indexes, as they take a long time to update.
- Change your database. MySQL is reportedly not as good as postgresql for these kinds of workloads.
- Batch updates to times when people aren't using the system (that's what many banks do).